# Python logging and Japanese (or any non-ascii)

Tags: python, django, logging, encoding, utf-8

After localisation of one legacy Django project (based on Django 1.1) to Japanese, some logs (not all of them) are outputting something like this, when locale is Japanese:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deploy/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 838, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/home/deploy/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 715, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/home/deploy/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 467, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What can be the cause of this and is there easy way to circumvent this? If not, how can I invetigate this issue more closely, as I even don't know which lines calling failing logs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html - really

Comment: @jsbueno but I do not know, where those strings are introduced in code. I cannot check every instance of calling logger, as codebase is large. And that trace only contains files/line numbers from standard python library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to find out what the strings are is to edit the logging module to give you some information about the error.  You don't have to keep the edits, just modify them long enough to find out what's causing the problem.

For example, at "/home/deploy/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 467 is this line:

```
s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
```

Change it to:

```
try:
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
except UnicodeError:
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
```

Then when the UnicodeDecodeError happens, you will be dropped into the debugger.  You can examine the format string and the record to determine what the problem is.

That might be too labor-intensive, though, so another option is:

```
try:
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
except UnicodeError:
    s = "*** Couldn't log properly: %r against %r" % (self._fmt, record.__dict__)
```

This way, the log will contain a line indicating the data that failed, and there will be one for each failing log line.  If you then examine the log file, you might find a number of problem lines.

Don't forget to keep an original version of the logging/__init__.py file so that you can revert to it when you are done debugging.

The difficult part of this problem is that there could be many offending lines, sprinkled throughout your code, and you can't catch them all with an ad-hoc technique like this unless you have 100% code coverage and can guarantee to hit all of them during testing.

For more on the underlying issues with Unicode in Python, see [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop The Pain?](http://bit.ly/unipain).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of exception I write this line in the top of each .py:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
```

From [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/):

> 1. Without interpreter line, using plain text:
>
>    ```
>      # This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
>      import os, sys
>      ...
>    ```